# Custom method in mapstruct

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I want to create a custom  method in my mapper (using mapstruct). 
My method consists of calculating the rating of a candidate from recommendations. (each  recommendation entity contains id of candidate and the rating). I want to get the average of those ratings using mapper.

I tried this method:

```
 @Mapper(componentModel="spring")
 public interface  CandidateMapper extends GenericMapper<Candidate, CandidateDTO> 
{
    @Autowired
    RecommendationRepository recommendationRepository; 

     default  CandidateDTO  getRating( Candidate candidate ) {
     Integer ratingAverage = 0; 
     List<Recommendation>  recomList =  recommendationRepository.findRecommendationByRecommended(candidate);
     recomList.forEach( (item) ->{
         ratingAverage= ratingAverage+ item.getRating(); 
    });  
     CandidateDTO candidateDTO = new CandidateDTO(); 
     candidate.setRating( ratingAverage / recomList.size());
    return  candidateDTO  ; 
}
```

But i couldn't autowire the repository  here  i get this error :

```
 The blank final field recommendation Repository may not have been initialized
```

How can i handle it please ?

Comment: try this

 @Mapper(componentModel="spring", imports = { java.util.Collections.class }, uses = { RecommendationRepository .class })

just take care of syntax here n there. I am posting using mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your mapper to use the `componentModel="spring"`:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring")
public abstract class CandidateMapper extends GenericMapper<Candidate, CandidateDTO> 
{
    @Autowired
    RecommendationRepository recommendationRepository; 
...
}
```

Comment: Yes i did, but hte same thing

Comment: Since all fields in an interface are public static final by default you need to change you have to define an abstract class for your mapper to allow Spring to inject the repository

Comment: how ?  sorry i didn't get well

Comment: @sudo means: it is an abstract class in stead of an interface. You cannot inject stuff on an interface.

Comment: Correct therefore the change in the code snippet. @SihemHcine Since I cannot see any mapping method in your code - for what do you use mapstruct / how does the GenericMapper looks like?